# C# Get Values from two different websites

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using `HTMLElementCollection`, `HtmlElement` to iterate through a website and using Get/Set attributes of a website HTML and returning it to a `ListView`. Is it possible to get values from website a and website b to return it to the `ListView`?

```
HtmlElementCollection oCol1 = oDoc.Body.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement oElement in oCol1)
{
    if (oElement.GetAttribute("id").ToString() == "search")
    {
        oElement.SetAttribute("value", m_sPartNbr);
    }
    if (oElement.GetAttribute("id").ToString() == "submit")
    {
        oElement.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}

HtmlElementCollection oCol1 = oDoc.Body.GetElementsByTagName("tr");
foreach (HtmlElement oElement1 in oCol1)
{
    if (oElement1.GetAttribute("data-mpn").ToString() == m_sPartNbr.ToUpper())
    {
        HtmlElementCollection oCol2 = oElement1.GetElementsByTagName("td");
        foreach (HtmlElement oElement2 in oCol2)
        {
            if (oElement2 != null)
            {
                if (oElement2.InnerText != null)
                {
                    if (oElement2.InnerText.StartsWith("$"))
                    {
                        string sPrice = oElement2.InnerText.Replace("$", "").Trim();
                        double dblPrice = double.Parse(sPrice);
                        if (dblPrice > 0)
                            m_dblPrices.Add(dblPrice);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, you should be able to use [`HttpWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) to send a request and get a response from an external website. It will be up to you to parse the value out that you need though if its not a REST api or some other kind of API. What do you mean by "get values"? Certain parts of a page? A REST api?

Comment: lets say I went to Bestbuy.com, and wanted to parse a price for a certain product, then return it to a list view. I'd like to do this with bestbuy.com and Amazon.com and return both prices to the list view.

Comment: Is HtmlAgilityPack in your future? https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ Note: I have no affiliation with them.

Comment: i'll take a looksie. thank you for the recommendation. I'm very raw to the http protocols. any other recommendations ? thank you !

Comment: if your trying to get values from a website that you don't own such as bestbuy, and your not using a public api, you most likely get blocked for hitting their max rate limit/scraping.  If you couldn't use a public api, you going to want to either request data in bulk and cache it, or your going to want to get multiple proxies to hit them from so you wont raise too much of an alarm

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but what do you mean by "multiple proxies to hit them..." ? can you explain a bit more please ?

Comment: If your program hammers their site too many times they may block you. Therefore, johnny is suggesting you take a distributed approach where you hit their site from many distributed programs, so that each one hits their site fewer times and you're less likely to get blocked. I wouldn't worry about doing that yet. Depending on how often you need to hit their site and if you're able to take advantage of techniques like caching, then there's may be no need to create multiple distributed programs. Don't prematurely optimize.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments mentioned the better approach would be to use HttpWebRequest to send a get request to www.bestbuy.com or whatever site.  What it returns is the full HTML code (what you see) which you can then parse through.  This kind of approach keeps you from seinding too many requests and getting blacklisted.  If you need to click a button or type in a text field its best to mimic human input to avoid being blacklisted also. I would suggest injecting a simple javascript into the page header or body and execute it from the app to send a 'onClick' event from the button (which would then reply with a new page to parse or display) or to modify the text property of something.

this example is in c++/cx but it originally came from a c# example.  the script sets the username and password text fields then clicks the login button:

```
    String^ script = "document.GetElementById('username-text').value='myUserName';document.getElementById('password-txt').value='myPassword';document.getElementById('btn-go').click();";
auto args = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<Platform::String^>();
args->Append(script);
create_task(wv->InvokeScriptAsync("eval", args)).then([this](Platform::String^ response){
    //LOGIN COMPLETE
});
```

//notes:  wv = webview

EDIT:
as pointed out the absolute best approach would be to get/request an api.  I was surprised to see that site mason pointed out for bestbuy developers.  Personally I have only tried to work with auto part stores who either laugh while saying I can't afford it or have no idea what I'm asking for and hang up (when calling corporate).

EDIT 2: in my code the site used was autozone.  I had to use chrome developer tools (f12) to get the names of the username, password, and button name.  From the developer tools you can also watch what is sent from your computer to the site/server.  This allows you to recreate everything and mimic javascript input and actions using post/get with HttpWebRequest.

Comment: This all assumes that Best Buy doesn't have an API. The "best" approach would be to check and see if they do. Even if they don't publicly mention one on their site, Emphatic may be able to get in touch with them to see if they have something available. A quick glance [shows promise](https://developer.bestbuy.com/).